# JavaFX: get percieved Brightness of a Color

Tags: java, colors, javafx, brightness

I got a coloured area in JavaFX and would like to display Text on it.
The text colour should be white or black depending on the percieved brightness
of the background. The following is the method given by [JavaFX.Color#getBrightness](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#getBrightness()). But this method is not convincing as I need to choose white for a Brightness up to 0.9.

```
if (getColor().getBrightness() < 0.9) {
   setStyle("-fx-text-fill: " + "white" + ";");
} else {
    setStyle("-fx-text-fill: " + "black" + ";");
}
```

Still, the result looks poor for many background colors:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you can define the background color in CSS too (maybe using a looked-up color), then you can use the css color function `ladder(...)` to define the text fill in terms of the background color. Something like:

```
.text-pane { /* pane containing the text */
    -text-background: red ;
    -fx-background-color: -text-background ;
}
.text-pane .text {
    -fx-fill: ladder(-text-background, white 0%, white 59%, black 60%, black 100%);
}
```

Note that you can use this technique if you want to dynamically choose the background at runtime, as you can use an inline style to change the value of the looked-up color you defined in the stylesheet:

```
Color color = ... ; // some color
String style = String.format("-text-background: rgba(%d, %d, %d, %f);",
    (int)(color.getRed()*255),
    (int)(color.getGreen()*255),
    (int)(color.getBlue()*255),
    color.getOpacity());
somePane.setStyle(style);
```

This is the same technique as is used by default by `Label` (and other controls). The looked-up color in that case is `-fx-background`. So if you do:

```
Label foo = new Label("Foo");
Label bar = new Label("Bar");
foo.setStyle("-fx-background: white;"); // automatically gets dark text
bar.setStyle("-fx-background: black;"); // automatically get white text
```

Complete demo:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LookedUpColorDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Text text1 = new Text("Foo");
        text1.getStyleClass().add("text");
        Text text2 = new Text("Bar");
        text2.getStyleClass().add("text");
        StackPane textPane1 = new StackPane(text1);
        textPane1.getStyleClass().add("text-pane");
        StackPane textPane2 = new StackPane(text2);
        textPane2.getStyleClass().add("text-pane");
        Label label1 = new Label("Foo label");
        Label label2 = new Label("Bar label");
        VBox root = new VBox(10, 
                new HBox(5, textPane1, createCheckBox(textPane1, "-text-background")),
                new HBox(5, textPane2, createCheckBox(textPane2, "-text-background")),
                new HBox(5, label1, createCheckBox(label1, "-fx-background")),
                new HBox(5, label2, createCheckBox(label2, "-fx-background"))
        );
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 250);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("looked-up-color-demo.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private CheckBox createCheckBox(Node node, String lookedUpColorName) {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
            if (isNowSelected) {
                node.setStyle(lookedUpColorName + ": black;");
            } else {
                node.setStyle(lookedUpColorName + ": white;");              
            }
        });
        return cb ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

With the css file looked-up-color-demo.css:

```
.label {
    -fx-background: white ;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-background ;
}
.text-pane {
    -text-background: white ;
    -fx-background-color: -text-background ;
}
.text-pane .text {
    -fx-fill: ladder(-text-background, white 0%, white 59%, black 60%, black 100%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that option, but I cannot use css colors because the colour is created not until runtime

Answer (score 1):

You may give a try to YUV (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV). In short: convert color in RGB to YUV and look at Y component (it's so called luma which is the brightness — in fact old monochromatic TV systems used this for picture encoding), as this, roughly, corresponds to brightness of a color if it were shown in gray scale (note that RGB#00F, blue, is rather dark while RGB#0F0, green, is rather light if you look at Y component, thou both G and B components have the same value) and this is what you are looking for. Comparing the brightness (luma) you can tell what is perceived as 'lighter' or 'darker' by a human and adapt your palette settings accordingly. However, `Color#getBrighteness()` might actually be the Y component of YUV (JavaDoc doesn't say so).